# str_replace() not displaying video when inserted after an image

Tags: php, html

I have a variable as follows:

```
$post= 'TO UPLOAD DO THIS <img src="Christmas.PNG"> and this <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aAkMkVFwAoo"></iframe>';
```

With the `<img>` tag I want to process the image to display diferently. I also want the video to be processed differently (customisable). I have done the following:

```
//Image processing:
 preg_match_all('/<img src=\"(.*?)\">/',$post,$matches);
    if(sizeof($matches[1])>0){
            $toRmove=[];
            $toAdd = [];
            foreach($matches[1] as $m){
                    $value = $m;
                    $toRemove[]='<img src="'.$value.'">';
                    $toAdd[]='<a href="images/'.$value.'" data-lightbox="Christmas"><img src="images/'.$value.'" width=20% height=20%></a>';
            }
            $new_message = str_replace($toRemove,$toAdd,$post);
            $post= $new_message;
    }

//video processing
preg_match_all('/<iframe src=\"(.*?)\">/',$post,$matches); 
if(sizeof($matches[1])>0){
        $toRmove=[];
        $toAdd = [];
        foreach($matches[1] as $m){
                $value = $m;
                $toRemove[] ='<iframe src="'.$value.'">';
                $toAdd[] ='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aAkMkVFwAoo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>';
            }
        $new_message = str_replace($toRemove,$toAdd,$post);
        $post= $new_message;
    
}

echo $post;
```

When I echo `$toAdd[0]`, the video displays correctly with what i want. However, after the `str_replace($toRemove,$toAdd,$post);` and then i echo `$post` the video just disappears but the image is still there and displaying correctly.

So the video processing is working but when it i go to add it, the video doesn't appear just blank.

Why is this occurring? Thanks.

Comment: View the page source and verify you get expected results

Comment: @JohnConde Sorry not sure what you mean by this? It doesnt display the corrected results.

Comment: The output of your PHP is HTML. Check the HTML and see if what it output is correct. If it is not, you can see what's wrong and then attempt to fix it

Comment: You have a typo. `$toRmove=[];` should be `$toRemove=[];`

Comment: @JohnConde It works in HTML file. But not in php file

Comment: That's *why* you need to view the HTML that is output by your PHP. So you can see what is wrong with it